# Bootstrap Modal data-backdrop="static"

Tags: model-view-controller, bootstrap-modal

I have a partial view in tab:

```html
<button class="tabs" disabled id="tab_six" onclick="setColor('tab_six');displayButton('button_six')" href="#documents" aria-controls="documents" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      Documents
</button>
```

The tab renders the partial view:

```html
<div class="tabDivs" id="docView" style="padding-top: 35px">
  @{Html.RenderPartial("GetDocuments");}
</div>
```

Within the partial view I have a modal popup. I want to the modal to use data-backdrop="static". When I do this the entire page modal and all are greyed out and I can't click anywhere or do anything. If I change the data-backdrop="static" data-backdrop="false" all works but I want to use data-backdrop="static". I believe it has something to do with the tab but not sure. Here is the partial view:

```html
<button class="tabs" disabled id="tab_six" onclick="setColor('tab_six');displayButton('button_six')" href="#documents" aria-controls="documents" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      Documents
    </button>
<div class="tabDivs" id="docView" style="padding-top: 35px">
  @{Html.RenderPartial("GetDocuments");}
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#staticBackdrop">
      Launch static backdrop modal
    </button>

<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">...</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
              Close
            </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```